# How do you set javascript src in html file for WebInvoke (WP7.5, Silverlight)

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am using the WebBrowser control in Windows Phone to invoke a javascript call.  Right now, the code works fine when I reference the script online.  However, when I reference it locally, it breaks.

I am thinking it has something to do with isolated storage and how WP7 apps install, but I wanted to get others takes.

The HTML file contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myJavascript.js"></script>
```

it works just fine when I do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/myJavascript.js"></script>'
```

And idea how I can reference the file locally?  I have it set to Content and Copy Always.

In the end, the real file is http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js 
I need to get it to work offline so my users don't need an internet connection to use my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot immediately see an issue with your approach, however, you have not shown the code you use to load the files into local storage. I would recommend looking at the sourcecode for [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/download/), which loads multiple files into isolated storage for rendering in a WebBrowser, to see how it does it. Here is the relevant opart of the PhoneGap code:

```
fileResourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file.path, UriKind.Relative));

if (fileResourceStreamInfo != null)
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream))
    {
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream.Length);

        string strBaseDir = AppRoot + file.path.Substring(0, file.path.LastIndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

        if(!appStorage.DirectoryExists(strBaseDir))
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Creating Directory :: " + strBaseDir);
            appStorage.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
        }

        // This will truncate/overwrite an existing file, or 
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream outFile = appStorage.OpenFile(AppRoot + file.path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Writing data for " + AppRoot + file.path + " and length = " + data.Length);
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(outFile))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that the source helped more than hinting to what to do, but this was exactly it.  The files need to be copied from the app install to isoloated storage to get this done right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Colin says, for relative paths to work in locally loaded HTML files all files must first be copied to Isolated storage and loaded from there.